# Sequence of integers that contains all combinations of digits with no repeating digits

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, soft-question, order-theory

What is the name of the infinite sequence of positive integers in some base *n* that contain all possible combinations of digits with no repeating consecutive digits and do not begin with zero?
For example: 
In base $2$: $1, 10, 101, 1010, 10101, 101010...$ 
In base $3$: $1, 2, 10, 12, 20 ,21, 101, 102, 120, 121, 201, 202, 210, 212, 1010, 1012... $ 
In base 4: $1, 2, 3, 10, 12, 13, 20, 21, 23, 30, 31, 32, 101, 102, 103, 120...$
Obviously, the sequence is specific to its base. For example, in binary the number $10101010101010$ belongs in the sequence, however in decimal this number is equal to $10922$, which is not allowed in the sequence, because it contains two consecutive $2$'s. 
I suppose, the question can be rephrased in terms of all possible sets with unique order of a certain number of unique elements such that no element can be put next to a same element and that the first element cannot be put in the first place.

Comment: It seems you want the sequence to be ordered, but that's not in your description (it wouldn't e unique without it). I've never heard a name for that, and as I don't see any uses I don't think it has any widely recognised name(s).

Comment: There's a notion of a [square free word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word)   on some set of letters...namely a word with no repeated subword.  But that would exclude numbers like $1010$.  I don't believe there's a name for the specific property you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sequences appear at OEIS.org as

- A000975 (base 2)
- A031941 (base 3)
- A031942 or A043090 (base 4)
- A031943 or A043091 (base 5)
- A043092 ... A043096 (base 6 through base 10)

They are not named, and no references are given, so it is unlikely that they have been named.